# Android can't connect webserver

Tags: java, php, android, web-services, android-intent

I use "xampp" build a web server,and create "abc.php" on C:\xampp\htdocs.

After finish all work , I link "localhost/abc.php".

use Pc google to cheak the URL can show "This is server's message".

So far is good.Until I wanna android connect webserver.

I try very much way (include close firewall or antivirus etc.) but still fail.

I have tried google(android phone) to connected "http://MyIP/abc.php",not through this program.

result is can show my "abc.php" in google(android phone).

but I don't know where error.
I can't use my program get the URL

```
package com.testdb;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private TextView textView;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        db message = new db();
        String msg = message.stringQuery("http://10.0.2.2/abc.php");
        textView.setText("Server message is "+msg);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

-

```
package com.testdb;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

public class db {

    public String stringQuery(String url){
        try
        {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost method = new HttpPost(url);
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(method);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            if(entity != null){
                return EntityUtils.toString(entity);
            }
            else{
                return "No string.";
            }
         }
         catch(Exception e){
             return "Network problem";
         }
    }
}
```

and this is my log

```
04-04 16:30:07.425: W/Trace(1183): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
04-04 16:30:16.906: E/Trace(1301): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
04-04 16:30:16.906: W/Trace(1301): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
04-04 16:30:16.916: W/Trace(1301): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
04-04 16:30:16.916: W/Trace(1301): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
04-04 16:30:17.006: W/Trace(1301): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
04-04 16:30:17.006: W/Trace(1301): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
04-04 16:30:17.796: W/Trace(1301): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
04-04 16:30:17.796: W/Trace(1301): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
04-04 16:30:17.816: W/Trace(1301): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
04-04 16:30:17.836: W/Trace(1301): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
04-04 16:30:18.046: D/libEGL(1301): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
04-04 16:30:18.066: D/(1301): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x2a0ac400, tid 1301
04-04 16:30:18.106: D/libEGL(1301): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
04-04 16:30:18.126: D/libEGL(1301): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
04-04 16:30:18.289: W/EGL_emulation(1301): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
04-04 16:30:18.309: D/OpenGLRenderer(1301): Enabling debug mode 0
04-04 16:30:18.309: W/Trace(1301): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
04-04 16:30:18.316: W/Trace(1301): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
04-04 16:30:18.316: W/Trace(1301): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
04-04 16:30:18.376: W/Trace(1301): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
04-04 16:30:18.386: W/Trace(1301): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
04-04 16:30:18.386: W/Trace(1301): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
04-04 16:30:18.386: W/Trace(1301): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
04-04 16:30:18.386: W/Trace(1301): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
04-04 16:30:18.386: W/Trace(1301): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
04-04 16:30:18.396: W/Trace(1301): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
04-04 16:30:18.486: W/Trace(1301): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
04-04 16:30:18.496: W/Trace(1301): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
04-04 16:30:18.496: W/Trace(1301): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
04-04 16:30:18.496: W/Trace(1301): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
04-04 16:30:18.689: W/Trace(1301): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
04-04 16:30:18.716: W/Trace(1301): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
04-04 16:30:18.786: W/Trace(1301): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
```

Comment: Is your Android phone connected to your WiFi network, or are you trying to connect to that URL over a cellular connection?

Comment: I want connect to that URL over a cellular connection,not connect WIFI net work

Comment: It is not recommended  to create class names with first letter in simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

10.0.2.2 is an IP address on your local network. It is not accessible from the Internet, so an Android phone with a cellular connection cannot connect to it. You need to run your Web application on a public hosting service, not on your local machine.

Comment: Yes,I know.Actually I use Fixed IP connect to.

Comment: If your local machine has a fixed external IP address, you need to use that address in your Android application. 10.0.2.2 is not an external IP address.

Comment: I sure my fixed IP is a effective,because I tried other machine connect to.Actually I always connect to "MyFixedIP/abc.php" on phone

Comment: 10.0.2.2 is not an external IP address. You can connect to that address from another machine on the same network, but you cannot connect to it from an external machine. Please see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network#Private_IPv4_address_spaces) if you don't believe me.

Comment: No.I belive,and I know what you say. 10.0.2.2 like Pc 127.0.0.1.  is can't connect for external machine Right ? why I use 10.0.2.2,because this is publice , I don't want public to my fixed IP

Comment: ok,we suppose my fixedIP is a 140.35.147.2,so 10.0.2.2 need change to 140.35.147.2 right ? but this way I has tried always can't connected.

Comment: Amazing,After del  android:targetSdkVersion="17" , I can connect and get abc.php . Do u know why ? If you know , plz teach me thx.